# Как в XCUITest определить состояние checkbox

Tags: swift, xcode

Пишу UITest на Swift с помощью XCUITest, столкнулся с проблемой: не могу определить состояние чекбокса.
Сценарий: в окне находится чекбокс, нужно определить есть ли в нем галка или нет.
Вроде проблема простая, но максимально не очевидная. В Accessebility Inspector есть параметр Value, когда чекбокс с галкой он равен 1, когда галки нет - 0. Как к нему привязаться - понятия не имею...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222966/from-an-xcuitest-how-can-i-check-the-on-off-state-of-a-uiswitch

Comment: Спасибо! В итоге у меня нашелся свой ответ, опишу его нииже.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел вот такое решение:

```
let value = myButton.value as? Bool
    if value == true {
        myButton.click()
    }
```